# Ionic v4 datepicker clear button?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to add a clear button to clear the value set with the date picker. I have added [pickerOptions]="customPickerOptionFrom" to my date picker and the following typescript.

```
  customPickerOptionFrom = {
    buttons: [{
      text: 'Clear',
      handler: () =>
        this.expirationDate = null
    }]
  }
```

This works and it sets up a clear button.... the problem is that all the other buttons [Cancel, Done] then disappear. Is there a way to just add this additional button? or does this method overwrite all buttons and force me to program them all?

EXPIREMENT:

```
customOptionsMfg: any = {
    buttons: [{
      text: 'Clear',
      handler: () =>
        this.productionDate = null
    }, {
      text: 'Cancel',
      role: 'cancel'
    },
    {
      text: 'Ok',
      handler: (data) => {
        this.productionDate = data.year.text + '-' + (data.month.value < 10 ? '0' + data.month.value.toString() : data.month.value.toString()) +
          + '-' + data.day.text
        console.log(this.productionDate);
      },
      role: 'ok'
    }]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you see, the property (buttons) is a list, so you can add as many items as you want, just add it.

buttons: [

```
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      role: 'cancel'
    },

{
  text: 'Clear',
  role: 'clear', // i don't know if putting this role will work
  handler: () =>
    this.expirationDate = null
},

    {
      text: 'Ok',
      role: 'ok'
    }
  ],
```

add this after PickerOptions

let picker = await this.pickerCtrl.create(opts);

picker.present();

```
picker.onDidDismiss().then(async data => {

  let num = await picker.getColumn('num');
    this.pickerData = num.options[num.selectedIndex].text;
    this.pickerDataPrevious = num.selectedIndex;
```

});

Comment: I changed it to the above but now when I click the OK button it no longer saves the value selected in the datepicker.

Comment: i edited the answer above check it out, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code, if you pass any buttons in then you take full responsibility for the buttons and the handlers.

Here is a snippet from the [generatePickerOptions()](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/2e02dc73190f19ed8108a121b9cb9ba362b15dcf/core/src/components/datetime/datetime.tsx) method:

```
// If the user has not passed in picker buttons,
// add a cancel and ok button to the picker
const buttons = pickerOptions.buttons;
if (!buttons || buttons.length === 0) {
  pickerOptions.buttons = [
    {
      text: this.cancelText,
      role: 'cancel',
      handler: () => {
        this.updateDatetimeValue(this.value);
        this.ionCancel.emit();
      }
    },
    {
      text: this.doneText,
      handler: (data: any) => {
        this.updateDatetimeValue(data);

        /**
         * Prevent convertDataToISO from doing any
         * kind of transformation based on timezone
         * This cancels out any change it attempts to make
         *
         * Important: Take the timezone offset based on
         * the date that is currently selected, otherwise
         * there can be 1 hr difference when dealing w/ DST
         */
        const date = new Date(convertDataToISO(this.datetimeValue));
        this.datetimeValue.tzOffset = date.getTimezoneOffset() * -1;

        this.value = convertDataToISO(this.datetimeValue);
      }
    }
  ];
}
```

It's looking to me like it gets pretty complicated if you want to do supply your own buttons as you can't just use this snippet above, it contains calls to private methods.

Based on what I'm reading I would be tempted to open a bug on Ionic to say that the feature is essentially unusable.

Unless I'm missing some theory? I don't know if you can write a handler that will work as if its slotted inside the class and be able to access the `this` and get at internal methods.

## Experiment

Perhaps try just slotting it all together and seeing if it works:

```
  customPickerOptionFrom = {
    buttons: [{
      text: 'Clear',
      handler: () =>
        this.expirationDate = null
    },
 {
      text: this.cancelText,
      role: 'cancel',
      handler: () => {
        this.updateDatetimeValue(this.value);
        this.ionCancel.emit();
      }
    },
    {
      text: this.doneText,
      handler: (data: any) => {
        this.updateDatetimeValue(data);

        /**
         * Prevent convertDataToISO from doing any
         * kind of transformation based on timezone
         * This cancels out any change it attempts to make
         *
         * Important: Take the timezone offset based on
         * the date that is currently selected, otherwise
         * there can be 1 hr difference when dealing w/ DST
         */
        const date = new Date(convertDataToISO(this.datetimeValue));
        this.datetimeValue.tzOffset = date.getTimezoneOffset() * -1;

        this.value = convertDataToISO(this.datetimeValue);
      }
    }
]
  }
```

Comment: I just added my current experiment to the original question.